# Как вывести содержимое set в цикле?

Tags: c++

Как вывести содержимое `set` в цикле?

Comment: Вывести куда? И в чём конкретно затруднение?

Answer (score 5):

```
for(auto i : set_object)
    cout << i << endl;
```

:)

Типа:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    set<int> s = { 1,2,45,23,19,8};
    for(auto i : s)
        cout << i << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно использовать обычный цикл `for` с итераторами, либо цикл на основе диапазона. Можно также использовать стандартные алгоритмы такие, как, например, `std::copy` или `std::copy_if`

Вот примеры вывода

```
std::set<int> s{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

for (std::set<int>::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << *it << ' ';
}
std::cout << std::endl;

for (const auto &item : s) std::cout << item << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;

std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
std::cout << std::endl;

std::copy_if(s.begin(), s.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "),
    [](int x) { return x % 2 != 0; });
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Вывод этих фрагментов кода будет следующим

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 3 5
```

Объявление итератора в этом цикле

```
for (std::set<int>::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
```

можно упростить

```
for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
```